# How to find files in Visual Studio 2015 that aren't part of source control

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I made some rather complicated changes to a file today and things stopped working in the application. I realized it was because I had accidentally deleted some code I didn't mean to. No big deal however, I can just compare my current code to the last checked in copy and find the code I deleted...

Except that the file wasn't IN source control. The rest of the project was. But for reasons unknown, this file, which is by no means a new file, was not there. And it wasn't showing up in pending changes. For some reason VS just never checked it in. (I was lucky enough that I hadn't exited VS and was able to undelete enough to get the original code back).

Is there a way, other then examining a few thousand files one by one by hand, to tell which files in a project/solution are NOT under source control?

Or barring that, is there a method similar to "get latest" but in reverse? Basically, I want to add everything in the solution to source control recursively (even though it should all already be under source control).

Answer (score 2):

**1) Use a Local Workspace for TFS**

If your TFS workspace is set to be a Local Workspace (see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/28/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces/) for a description of what this means), running `tf status` will show you a list of detected changes.  This will be any files that have been added or deleted from disk without being explicitly pended to source control.

Local workspaces have a few other niceties, like being able to perform most of your editing without the Read-Only bit set and without needing a connection to your TFS server to checkout a file.  And it does incur some overhead to track all of those changes locally, so there is a tradeoff.  The blog post covers most of the details.

You can toggle a workspace between Server and Local with the following steps:

1. Open your workspace settings (either through VS or running `tf workspace`)
2. Expand the Advanced settings
3. Change the dropdown labeled Location (it should allow either Local or Server)

This process takes a little while to run as it creates the local cache or syncs the cached state back to the server (depending on which way you're changing it), but you don't have to create a new workspace.

**2) Use Source Control Explorer**

The Source Control Explorer window in VS has a button on its toolbar to compare folders.  This allows you to compare the folder in source control with the folder on disk, including files that exist only on either side, or files with differences.